# Expires vs max-age, which one takes priority if both are declared in a HTTP response?

Tags: http, http-headers, cache-control, http-caching

If a HTTP response that returns both Expires and max-age indications which one is used?

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Expires: Tue, 15 May 2008 07:19:00 GMT
```

Considering that each one refers to a different point in time.

Comment: How the browser cache will clear in this scenario?
Will it request to cloudflare again according to max-age ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

See this answer:

[Difference between three .htaccess expire rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740952/difference-between-three-htaccess-expire-rules/3746325#3746325)

> If a response includes both an Expires header and a max-age directive,
>   **the max-age directive overrides the Expires header**, even if the
>   Expires header is more restrictive. This rule allows an origin server
>   to provide, for a given response, a longer expiration time to an
>   HTTP/1.1 (or later) cache than to an HTTP/1.0 cache. This might be
>   useful if certain HTTP/1.0 caches improperly calculate ages or
>   expiration times, perhaps due to desynchronized clocks.

Comment: Is it that only in Apache or it is a general rule? Thanks.

Comment: This applies in general; the paragraph above comes from section 14.9.3 of the HTTP/1.1 specification.

Answer (score 14):

This case is explained in the official [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) on W3C.

> The max-age directive takes priority over Expires