# Kotlin/Ktor call.response.cookies.append() set expiration time

Tags: kotlin, cookies, session-cookies, ktor

I want to set a cookie on my website using `call.response.cookies.append("token", "$token")`.
How can I set up an expiration date for this cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
val myCookie = Cookie(
        name = token,
        value = "$token",
        maxAge = 10
    )
call.response.cookies.append(myCookie)
```

The cookie data class is as follows from the [documentation](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-http/io.ktor.http/-cookie/index.html):

```
data class Cookie(
    val name: String, 
    val value: String, 
    val encoding: CookieEncoding = CookieEncoding.URI_ENCODING, 
    val maxAge: Int = 0, 
    val expires: GMTDate? = null, 
    val domain: String? = null, 
    val path: String? = null, 
    val secure: Boolean = false, 
    val httpOnly: Boolean = false, 
    val extensions: Map<String, String?> = emptyMap()
)
```

So for giving expiration time for a cookie, you can use either `maxAge` (which expects the time in seconds) or `expiry` (which expects a GMTDate). If both are set then `maxAge` takes priority (Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549177/expires-vs-max-age-which-one-takes-priority-if-both-are-declared-in-a-http-resp) Q & A)

Additionally from the documentation itself:

> A cookie with neither expires nor maxAge is a session cookie.