# Is Expires header not needed now?

Tags: http, caching, cdn, cache-control, expires-header

I see big player (i.e. akamai) started to drop the `Expires` header all together and only use `Cache-Control`, e.g.

```
curl -I https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/395029_379645875452936_1719075242_n.jpg

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Sun, 25 Nov 2012 16:46:43 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=1209600
```

So still any reason to keep using `Expires`?

Comment: See also   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479581/does-cache-control-s-maxage-header-override-expires-header-for-browser-cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Cache-Control* was introduced in HTTP 1.1 to replace *Expires*. If both headers are present, [*Cache-Control* is preferred over *Expires*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.9.3):

> If a response includes both an Expires header and a max-age
> directive, the max-age directive overrides the Expires header, even
> if the Expires header is more restrictive. This rule allows an origin
> server to provide, for a given response, a longer expiration time to
> an HTTP/1.1 (or later) cache than to an HTTP/1.0 cache. This might be
> useful if certain HTTP/1.0 caches improperly calculate ages or
> expiration times, perhaps due to desynchronized clocks.

But there are still clients out there that can only HTTP 1.0. So for HTTP 1.0 requests/responses, you should still use *Expires*.